# linking html and css

Tags: html, css

I can't get the below `HTML` and `CSS` files to link.
I have saved the files as `.html` and `.css` and they are both saved in the same folder so not that is not the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>
uni
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.h1 {
  color: #4d79ff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: put the above css inside <style>Your css</style> and this should be either inside head or body not outside html. Also remove the dot.

Comment: I would guess your style is linked. You are applying the style to the class called 'h1' not the markup. Remove the `.` before the `h1` to style that element

Comment: Read some basic CSS tutorials on selectors and learn about the difference between tags (element names) and classes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with how you link your stylesheet, it's with the contents of it.

The `.h1` would select any tag with a class of h1. This is called the class selector.

The element selector is just the element; ie. `h1 { /*styles here*/ }`

**So to fix your example you either need to change your html to this: (no changes made to css)**

```css
.h1 {
  color: #4d79ff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="h1">
uni
</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

**Or you change your css to this: (no changes made to html)**

```css
h1 {
  color: #4d79ff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
uni
</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here is an article about css selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the style to `.h1` class, not `h1` tag.
To make it apply to the tag - not class, you have to remove the dot at the beginning:

```
h1 {
  color: #4d79ff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[Element selectors reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element.asp)
[Class selectors reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)

Answer (score -2):

make a new file ***main.css*** (extension of .css) and put the below code in it

```
`.h1 {
  color: #4d79ff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute
 }`
```

In html between  tags you write down the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```